# GKE Taints come back after removing them when ClusterManagerInternal.PatchCluster runs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have recently started experiencing an issue with our k8s cluster running on gke where it re-applies taints that we have previously removed.

Our process goes as follows:
We create a new nodepool using the `gcloud container node-pools create` adding a taint using the `--node-taints` option.
The taint we add: `setup-phase=whitelisting:NoSchedule`

We do this in order to not have any pods start on the new node pool until we have done ip whitelisting with our third parties.
Once we are done with whitelisting we remove the taints using
`kubectl taint nodes <node_name> setup-phase-` on each of the nodes in the nodepool.
The pods spins up without any issue after this.

This approach was working fine for months without any issues.

We did this same thing on 01 February 2022.

We noticed on 08 February 2022 that the taints somehow re-appeared on the nodepool. We then realized that the nodepool metadata still had
the taint applied to it, and not just the nodes.
The exact time the taints got applied was when `google.container.internal.ClusterManagerInternal.PatchCluster` ran the previous night.

We then assumed it to be our mistake as we only removed the taints from the nodes themself and not the pool. This has never happened before but we might just have gotten lucky.

We subsequently ran `gcloud beta container node-pools update` with the `--node-taints ""` option. This removed the taint from the node pool as well as the nodes themselves.

That same night, another `google.container.internal.ClusterManagerInternal.PatchCluster` ran. Somehow the taints got re-applied once again.
Checking the nodepool this time, showed no taints. But the nodes themselves had the taints applied. Running `gcloud beta container node-pools update` again setting the taint to nothing had no effect. Running `kubectl taint nodes <node_name> setup-phase-` on the individual nodes did remove the taints.

Last night it happened again, re-applying the taints that are not specified anywhere in our configurations anymore. Had to run `kubectl taint nodes <node_name> setup-phase-` again to get them to go away.

We re-created the nodepool following our process mentioned above but this time using the `gcloud beta container node-pools update` with the `--node-taints ""` instead. We're hoping that whatever is causing this, is resolved on the new nodepool. This was done today so not sure yet if this resolves the issue. We'll have to wait for `ClusterManagerInternal.PatchCluster` to run again before we can see.

Something else we did notice was on the compute engine instance templates. When creating the new nodepool, it creates a new instance template for each node. Once we remove the taints, an additional template is created for each node with the taint removed, but the previous templates that were created during nodepool creation(the ones with the taints) does not go away. It simply has no value under "In use by" column. Re-creating the nodepool removed both the ones that were in use and the ones that were left behind the previous time.

Anyone understand what is going on here? Any feedback appreciated as we're out of ideas

Update:
I see `google.container.internal.ClusterManagerInternal.PatchCluster` did run last night on the newly created nodepool. Taints did not re-appear this time.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this...seeing this behavior on GKE 1.19.15-gke.1300.  I used your --node-taints="" method, hopefully that removes them permanently.